# Create a dataframe from a list of names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like so:

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
B<-c(5,6,5,4,3)
C<-c(6,6,6,6,6)
D<-c(3,3,2,4,5)
E<-c(7,6,5,4,3)
DF<-data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
```

I also have individual vectors:

```
AA<-c(8,8,8,8,8)
BB<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
CC<-c(4,4,4,4,3)
DD<-c(2,2,2,2,3)
EE<-c(7,7,7,7,6)
```

My goal is to make a new data frame by referencing the above names. I have a loop function that creates a list of how I'd like the data frame to be organized. The result looks like this:

```
mylist<-list('DF$A','AA','DF$B','BB','DF$C','CC','DF$D','DD','DF$E','EE')
```

How can I create a new data frame based on the above list?

Something akin to this:

```
MyDataFrame<-data.frame(mylist)
```

Which obviously doesn't work. But something that would give the same result as this:

```
MyDataFram<-data.frame(DF$A, AA,DF$B,BB,DF$C,CC,DF$D,DD,DF$E,EE)
```

Without having to specify each term

Comment: Did you look at `cbind`?

Comment: I can use cbind on the actual data (cbind(MyDataFrame,DF$A)). But my list just contains the character version, so I can't use cbind(MyDataFrame,"DF$A") or more correctly (cbind(MyDataFrame,mylist[1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example might be of help

```
a<-c(4,4,4,4,3) #data 1
b<-c(2,2,2,2,3) #data 2
l<-list(a=a,b=b) #make list (I assume you already have this organized)

#depend on how you want to compile your data use either 'rbind' or 'cbind'
d<-data.frame(do.call('rbind',l)) 
> d
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
a  4  4  4  4  3
b  2  2  2  2  3

d<-data.frame(do.call('cbind',l))
> d
  a b
1 4 2
2 4 2
3 4 2
4 4 2
5 3 3
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this same thing with the list above (aka- a character list corresponding to variable names)

Comment: @Vint please update your question with exactly what output you want (provide a short example) - it will be then easier for us to modify our answers

Comment: I'm looking for the exact output of the above "MyDataFram<-data.frame(DF$A, AA,DF$B,BB,DF$C,CC,DF$D,DD,DF$E,EE)". But am stuck using a list of the same format of "mylist" above to create my data frame

Comment: please edit your question with the expected output of the "data.frame(DF$A, AA,DF$B,BB,DF$C,CC,DF$D,DD,DF$E,EE)"

Answer (score 0):

Consider `mapply` to column bind element-wise across two dataframes:

```
# CREATE A DATAFRAME OF SEPARATE VECTORS
otherDF <- data.frame(AA, BB, CC, DD, EE)

# VECTOR OUTPUT OF COLUMN NAMES
nms <- mapply(c, names(DF), names(otherDF))

# LIST OUTPUT OF DATAFRAMES
dfs <- mapply(function(x,y) data.frame(cbind(x,y)), DF, otherDF, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
# dfs <- Map(function(x,y) data.frame(cbind(x,y)), DF, otherDF)  # EQUIVALENT CALL

# COMBINED DATAFRAME
df <- setNames(do.call(cbind, dfs), nms)
df
#   A AA B BB C CC D DD E EE
# 1 1  8 5  1 6  4 3  2 7  7
# 2 2  8 6  2 6  4 3  2 6  7
# 3 3  8 5  3 6  4 2  2 5  7
# 4 4  8 4  4 6  4 4  2 4  7
# 5 5  8 3  5 6  3 5  3 3  6
```

Answer (score 0):

`as.data.frame` with `col.names = names_df` just passed the list with the name of the vectors.You'll just need to change the dot to `_` or other character or just "mask" the `$` sign. Hope it helps and is your answer you looking for.

```
##this info:S3 method for class 'list'
as.data.frame(x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, ...,
              cut.names = FALSE, col.names = names(x), fix.empty.names = TRUE,
              stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.data.frame.html

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
B<-c(5,6,5,4,3)
C<-c(6,6,6,6,6)
D<-c(3,3,2,4,5)
E<-c(7,6,5,4,3)
DF<-data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
DF

AA<-c(8,8,8,8,8)
BB<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
CC<-c(4,4,4,4,3)
DD<-c(2,2,2,2,3)
EE<-c(7,7,7,7,6)

names_df <- c('DF$A','AA','DF$B','BB','DF$C','CC','DF$D','DD','DF$E','EE')
str(names_df)

mylist<-list( DF$A ,AA,DF$B,BB,DF$C,CC,DF$D,DD,DF$E,EE)
str(mylist)


df <- as.data.frame(mylist, col.names = names_df)
df
```

[image]